# Display Epub Contnet based on the device view size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, epub

I am working in epub reader Creation. following things i did,

1. Unzip the .epub file
2. From that I read table of content based on the .ncx file
3. I display the content uiwebview.(If I want display chapter-1 means chapter-1.xml file full content shown in webview scrollable state).
4. I used UISwipeGestureRecognizer for page navigation based on the .opf file.

based on those things i can see the .epub file in uiwebview scrollable state.

Now I want to do following things (in uiwebview):

1.To display the content based on the view size.

2.To display number of columns based on the user requirement.

3.To display the page numbers accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1) for your first question as per i know you want display page according to your size

try with this java script

```
In webViewDidFinishLoad

NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", _webview.frame.size.height, _webview.frame.size.width];
```

2) for counting page in your chapter

```
 In webViewDidFinishLoad

 int totalWidth = [[_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];
    ttlChapterPage = (int)((float)totalWidth/_webview.bounds.size.width);
```